# Issues with conditional rendering react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have read quite a lot about react conditional rendering on the official docs and on STO as well but I have some issues and doubts.

```
     return (
        
        <div className="container is-fluid">
          {games.map((game) => (
            
           <div className="gameContainer" key={game.id}>
             
    
        {!!`${game.live_embed_url}` && (<iframe src= {`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`} frameBorder="2" allowFullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620">
</iframe>)}
    
    
            <h2 className="h2__whiteuk-text-large">{game.name}{game.live_embed_url}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
```

My objective here is I'm trying to check if the value of `{game.embed_url}` is NULL then no `<iframe>` should be rendered, else `<iframe>` should be rendered,

Ofc all this would be much simpler with a if/else but since I'm inside the return I cannot use that and I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

I'm sorry if the question is too basic but I have spent too much time trying to figure it out and just keep breaking my application.

Comment: Try { `${game?.live_embed_url}` && <iframe ...> </Iframe> } . Using optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the ternary operator in this type of situation:

```
{
game.live_embed_url ?
    (<iframe src= {`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`} frameBorder="2" allowFullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620">
</iframe>) 
    : null
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I wasn't able to figure out that last :null part, Thank you so much I appreciate the quick help.

Answer (score 2):

just extract the logic to a function and use the if:

```
const renderIframe = (game) => {
  if (!game.live_embed_url) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <iframe
      src={`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`}
      frameBorder="2"
      allowFullScreen="true"
      scrolling="no"
      height="378"
      width="620"
    ></iframe>
  );
};

return (
  <div className="container is-fluid">
    {games.map((game) => (
      <div className="gameContainer" key={game.id}>
        {renderIframe(game)}

        <h2 className="h2__whiteuk-text-large">
          {game.name}
          {game.live_embed_url}
        </h2>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

**EDIT:**
Just as a note to the OP and whoever reads this, the pattern they are trying to do is called short circuiting and can be considered an anti pattern by some people when you use it in place of an if. Example: https://www.codereadability.com/dont-use-short-circuiting-when-you-want-an-if-statement/

I personally have nothing against it but think using `ifs` improves readability.

Comment: This seems to work, But I have a question regarding your code, `if (!game.live_embed_url)` sorry if this sounds silly but how does that code work? I mean I thought about the same logic but I thought I cannot access the {game.live_embed_url} till after the map?

Comment: You are accessing it after, the function renderIframe(game) is called from inside the map and receives the game as a parameter. You might be confusing the function declaration, which in this case is before, with the actual call of the function

Comment: Yes I understand that better now and wow, I can really apply this logic to so many other things I'm trying to build, I appreciate the help and explanation! Thank you a ton

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `!!` to check for value. Right now what's happening is, if game.embed_url is undefined, !!`${game.live_embed_url}` will evaluate to `!!'undefind'` which will evaluate to `true` because of the 'undefind' string.

In javascript any no-empty string evaluates to `true`.

You can try the following

```js
{game.live_embed_url && (<iframe src= {`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`} frameBorder="2" allowFullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620">
</iframe>)}
```

Comment: I believe this will also return `undefined` if `game.live_embed_url` is `undefined`, which is why it is recommended to use the ternary operator instead of this syntax. It allows you to have better control over what gets returned in the "falsey" case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&` this way

```js
return (    
    <div className="container is-fluid">
        {games.map((game) => (
            <div className="gameContainer" key={game.id}>
                {game.live_embed_url && (
                    <iframe 
                        src= {`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`} frameBorder="2" 
                        allowFullscreen="true" 
                        scrolling="no" 
                        height="378" 
                        width="620"
                    />
                )}
                <h2 className="h2__whiteuk-text-large">
                    {game.name}
                    {game.live_embed_url}
                </h2>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you try to check the `game.live_embed_url` inside string literal. In Vanilla Javascript, every String is considered true except empty string `""`. Try discarding string template:

```
game.live_embed_url && (<iframe src= {`${game.live_embed_url}&parent=localhost`} frameBorder="2" allowFullscreen="true" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620">
```